# Adding inheritance to a class programmatically in python?

Tags: python

Can I make a class inherit a class "in-program" in Python?

heres what i have so far:

```
base = list(cls.__bases__)
base.insert(0, ClassToAdd )
base = tuple( base )
cls = type( cls.__name__, base, dict(cls.__dict__) )
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new class definition, or add a parent to an existing class definition, or add a parent to an existing instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example, using Greg Hewgill's suggestion:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def beep(self):
        print('Hi')

class Bar(object):
    x = 1  

bar = Bar()
bar.beep()
# AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'beep'

Bar = type('Bar', (Foo,object), Bar.__dict__.copy())
bar.__class__ = Bar
bar.beep()
# 'Hi'
```

Comment: This approach didn't work for me when Foo was a child class as well. The attributes on Foo inherited from it's parents were ignored.

Comment: Check below for how I fixed this specific issue

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495333/pydantic-dynamically-create-a-model-with-multiple-base-classes

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) built-in function has a three argument form that can do this:

> **type**(*name*, *bases*, *dict*)
>
> Return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the `class` statement. The *name* string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute; the *bases* tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute; and the *dict* dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is not to change the class hierarchy dynamically but to decorate instances of objects with the new functionality.  This is generally cleaner and easier to debug, because you only change objects that your code is in controls without having to make a cross cutting change to the whole class hierarchy.

```
def extend_object(obj):
    class ExtensionClass(obj.__class__):
        def new_functionality(self):
             print "here"
    obj.__class__ = ExtensionClass

b = Foo()
extend_object(b)
b.new_functionality()
#prints "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution that does take into account base classes of both the parent and the child classes.

```
import inspect    

def inherit_from(Child, Parent):

    # Prepare bases
    child_bases = inspect.getmro(Child)
    parent_bases = inspect.getmro(Parent)
    bases = tuple([item for item in parent_bases if item not in child_bases]) + child_bases

    # Construct the new return type
    Child = type(Child.__name__, bases, Child.__dict__.copy())

    return Child
```