# Pydantic - Dynamically create a model with multiple base classes?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, pydantic

From the [pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) I understand this:

```py
import pydantic

class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

class Student(pydantic.BaseModel):
    semester: int

# this works as expected
class Student_User(User, Student):
    building: str

print(Student_User.__fields__.keys())
#> dict_keys(['semester', 'id', 'name', 'building'])
```

However, when I want to create a similar object dynamically (following the section [dynamic-model-creation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation)):

```py
# this results in a TypeError
pydantic.create_model("Student_User2", __base__=(User, Student))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Question: How to dynamically create a class like `Student_User`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `pydantic==1.9.2`,

```
Student_User2 = pydantic.create_model("Student_User2", __base__=(User, Student), building=(str, ...))
```

runs successfully and

```
print(Student_User2.__fields__.keys())
```

returns

```
dict_keys(['semester', 'id', 'name', 'building'])
```

Comment: I can confirm this with python 3.8.6 and pydantic 1.9.0. Seems like either a new pydantic version or a new python version or the interplay of both has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Its not the answer to the original question, but if you are like me and all you care about is having a model which holds fields of other models, this should be a solutions.

```py
Student_User = pydantic.create_model("Student_User", **{
    **{key: (value.type_, value.default) for key, value in User.__fields__.items()},
    **{key: (value.type_, value.default) for key, value in Student.__fields__.items()},
    **{"building": (str, '')},
})
```

Essentially, we are dynamically creating a new pydantic model and we are setting its fields to be the fields of our other models plus an additional custom field.

Note:
OP included these lines in his question:

```py
print(Student_User.__fields__.keys())
#> dict_keys(['semester', 'id', 'name', 'building'])
```

So, my guess is that his end goal was copying the fields from the other models and having a model created from multiple bases was just a method of achieving it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I stated that my answer doesn't answer the original question, however I did explain why it is still relevant in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with `pydantic` but with how python handles multiple inheritances. I am assuming in the above code, you created a class which has both the fields of `User` as well as `Student`, so a better way to do that is

```py
class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

class Student(User):
    semester: int

class Student_User(Student):
    building: str
```

This gets your job done. So, now if you want to create these models dynamically, you would do

```py
pydantic.create_model("Student_User2", building=(str, ...), __base__=Student)
```

Obviously, `building` is the new model's field, so you can change that as you want

So, the final complete code would look something like this

```py
import pydantic

class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

class Student(User):
    semester: int

class Student_User(Student):
    building: str

print(Student_User.__fields__.keys())

model = pydantic.create_model("Student_User2", building=(str, ...), __base__=Student)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def merge_models(name: str, *models: Iterable[BaseModel]) -> BaseModel:

    fields = {}
    for model in models:
        f = {k: (v.annotation, v) for k, v in model.model_fields.items()}
        fields.update(f)
    return pydantic.create_model(name, **fields)

class Student_User(merge_models("Student_User_Base",User, Student)):
    building: str
```

This will work without warnings.